# Los ng-atributos de AngularJS no pasan el validador de W3C

Tags: html, angularjs, validación, angular-directivas

Cuando intento validar una página hecha con AngularJS, me encuentro con que no valida correctamente y lanza numerosos errores en el código (generalmente es el mismo repetido). El problema viene de que los atributos `ng-` no se consideran estándar y generan el fallo.

Por ejemplo, este simple código en AngularJS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Test con Angular</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body ng-app ng-init="nombre='Juan'; apellido='Tanamera';">
    <strong>Nombre:</strong> {{nombre}}<br />
    <strong>Apellido:</strong> <span ng-bind="apellido"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cuando lo paso por el [validador de código de W3C](https://validator.w3.org/), me lanza el siguiente error:

> **Error: Attribute `ng-app` not allowed on element `body` at this point.**
>
> From line 8, column 1; to line 8, column 61
>
> ```
> ↩</head>↩↩<body ng-app ng-init="firstName = 'John'; lastName = 'Doe';">↩  <st
> ```

Y ahora las preguntas:

- ¿Debería preocuparme por que no se valide el código?
- ¿Hay alguna manera de cambiarlo para que sí pase el validador?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Debería preocuparme por que no se valide el código?

Un ejemplo: Si validamos [google.es](https://www.google.es/) en W3C tendríamos de momento [22 errores](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F)!

En [este video (inglés)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPBACTS-tyg) explica google que no validan por tema de rendimiento.

**Hay que preocuparse entonces?**

**Sí**, pero hay que diferenciar entre errores sintáctica del documento y entre errores ocasionados por atributos no conocidos.

Algunos errores comunes en W3C-Validator:

- [Vendor Prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix): `-webkit-` `-moz-` `-o-` `-ms-`
- `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"`

Los atributos no conocidos, como en tu ejemplo `ng-app` `ng-init`, no son errores que afectan a la representación de la página, pero si da error en el *W3C - Validator*, sin embargo, errores de sintáctica del documento si te podría afectar (según navegador y error) la representación de la página y por su puesto daría error en el *W3C - Validator*.

---

> ¿Hay alguna manera de cambiarlo para que sí pase el validador?

Como ya lo ha mencionado el compañero [Ziul en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38029/6491) se puede añadir a los atributos
   `ng-app` `ng-init` etc. el prefijo `data-` cual no tiene ninguna [diferencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589915/2097224) al usarlo y pasaría por el *W3C - Validator* como válido.

---

**Conclusión** (personal):

Hay que minimizar y/o eliminar todos los errores posibles que nos brinda el validador del *W3C* y tener en cuenta que si es por error de sintáctica o por atributos no conocidos.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS (Angular 1) permite los prefijos x- y data- para sus atributtos personalizados. Puedes usar `data-ng-app`, `data-ng-bind` y `data-ng-init`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Test con Angular</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body data-ng-app data-ng-init="nombre='Juan'; apellido='Tanamera';">
    <strong>Nombre:</strong> {{nombre}}<br />
    <strong>Apellido:</strong> <span data-ng-bind="apellido"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```